# MYSQL limit CPU resources

Tags: mysql, limit, cpu, qos

A couple days ago a client called me because their server (30 concurrent users) was hunging each a week. After a research, I detected that one report was using a massive use of the server disk for almost 7 minutes.

...Despite the fact than the programmer will change the report...

I wonder if exist something like a QoS for MYSQL (as the routers)? There is some way to limit the percentage of disk (or CPU or something) in use?

Comment: What do you mean massive use of the server disk? Isn't the DB in a dedicated machine? Or was it doing reads/writes for 7 mins?

Comment: reads/writes. (Before that report, more than 1 year without hungs). Still researching, looks like there is not way to define a resource limit to the MYSQL users. If can, one will take the 100%.

Comment: Either the program needs to change the report or you need to change your schema and configuration. I think there is a way to kill a query that takes too much time but that is not a solution because the data I assume are needed. You need to see if the current set up can be changed to scale

Comment: yes, you can kill an unpleasant query. Also, the programmer will modify the report. Sadly looks like there no way to say to MySQL: "dont give more than 10% to any resource".

Comment: :I don't think it makes sense to do that. The idea is that the dbas build the servers according to needs. E.g. a server dedicated for heavy queries or a server only for small requests. If that limit was in MySQL it would easily kill many valid queries due to e.g. multiple reports running or any other reason

Comment: https://www.toadworld.com/platforms/oracle/b/weblog/archive/2013/12/02/how-to-limit-cpu-consumption-of-a-database oracle looks like makes sense to do that

Comment: It seems to me that what they do is try to help the multithreading aspect of the db and control how many treads are used. I didn't read anything about cpu limit of resources in the page you linked to